# A variable inside an asset declaration in Twig

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

My inline style looks like:

```
style="background-image: url({{ asset('bundles/testblog/images/id.jpg') }});"
```

the part `id` of the url must change depending on a varibale. How can I make this happen inside the asset.

I tried :

```
style="background-image: url({{ asset('bundles/testblog/images/'{{variable}}'.jpg') }});"
```

But to no avail.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `~` for [concatenation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators),

```
style="background-image: url({{ asset('bundles/testblog/images/' ~ variable ~ '.jpg') }});"
```

**Also,**

You don’t need to nest `{{ ... }}` delimiters. The ones you used to wrap `asset()` call are also used to print any other variable they contain.

Answer (score 6):

```
style="background-image: url({{ asset('bundles/testblog/images/' ~ variable ~ '.jpg') }});"
```